# How to use replace text function in a column using another table as a "lookup table" reference?

Tags: postgresql, string, string-manipulation

Here's some examples to show what I'm after. The source table (the one to have its string values changed):

```
| string                |
|-----------------------|
| abc${hello}123        |
| def${yolo}321         |
| lol${hello}wow${yolo} |
```

And here is the lookup table, the one it will be used to replace the values:

```
| source   | replacement |
|----------|-------------|
| ${hello} | :)          |
| ${yolo}  | :0          |
```

And this is the result I want:

```
|  replaced  |
|------------|
| abc:)123   |
| def:0321   |
| lol:)wow:0 |
```

I tried something like this, but it's not returning what I expect:

```sql
WITH replacements AS(
SELECT *
FROM (
VALUES 
('${hello}', ':)'),
('${yolo}', ':0')
) AS sr(source,replacement)
),
strings AS(
SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES
    ('abc${hello}123'),
    ('def${yolo}321'),
    ('lol${hello}wow${yolo}')
) s(string)
)
SELECT replaced
FROM strings,
LATERAL (
  SELECT replace(string, source, replacement) replaced 
  FROM replacements
) aux
;
```

It returns:

```
| replaced         |
|------------------|
| abc:)123         |
| abc${hello}123   |
| def${yolo}321    |
| def:0321         |
| lol:)wow${yolo}  |
| lol${hello}wow:0 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using a function might be the easiest solution. To avoid reading the list of lookups for each function call, they could be passed as an array, that's only retrieved once:

```
create or replace function replace_lookup(p_input text, p_replacements lookup[])
  returns text
as
$$
declare
  l_rec lookup;
  l_result text := p_input;
begin
  foreach l_rec in array p_replacements loop
    l_result := replace(l_result, l_rec.source, l_rec.replacement);
  end loop;
  
  return l_result;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then use it like this:

```
with lookups as materialized (
  select array_agg(l) as replacements
  from lookup l
)
select store.*, replace_lookup(name, replacements)
from store
  cross join lookups;
```

Obviously this won't work efficiently if the lookup table contains millions of rows. But for a few thousands, this should work just fine I assume.

Not sure if this is faster or slower than the recursive approach, but in my opinion it's easier to understand and maintain.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/k-N7olvV)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have

- `source_table(id integer primary key, string text)`
- `lookup_table(id integer primary key, lookup text, value text)`

Here is the query which recursively replaces markers. The query is not efficient but can give you an idea.

```
WITH RECURSIVE rt(id, string, replaced) AS (
    select st.id, st.string, st.string  from source_table st
  UNION ALL
    select distinct on (rt.id)
        rt.id, rt.string, replace(rt.replaced, l.lookup, l.value)
      from rt
      join lookup_table l ON rt.replaced SIMILAR TO concat('%', l.lookup, '%')  -- you may need escape character...
)
SELECT rt.* FROM rt
  left join lookup_table l ON rt.replaced SIMILAR TO concat('%', l.lookup, '%')
  where l.id is null
```

```
| id | string                | replaced   |
|---:|:----------------------|:-----------|
| 1  | abc${hello}123        | abc:)123   |
| 2  | def${yolo}321         | def:0321   |
| 3  | lol${hello}wow${yolo} | lol:)wow:0 |
```

Fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4TxFkRgS)